# strategy.exit() in pinescript doesnt exit on exact price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

in v5 of pine Script i have below strategy and i want to exit whenever my stop or limit reached but sometimes they've ignored.
i want to achieve 0.5 percent for stoploss and takeprofit but i've get 0.5,2.2 or higher.

```
IsLong() =>
    strategy.position_size > 0
IsShort()=>
    strategy.position_size < 0

   currEntryPrice_short = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
    curTpPrice_short = (currEntryPrice_short *(100 -  v3takeprofit_input))/100 
    currStopPrice_short = (currEntryPrice_short * (100 + v3stoploss_input))/100 
    if low <= curTpPrice_short and IsShort()
        strategy.exit("Take Profit  Hit", "Short", limit =curTpPrice_short)

    if high >= currStopPrice_short and IsShort()
        strategy.exit("Stop Loss Hit", "Short", stop=currStopPrice_short)

    currEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
    curTpPrice = (currEntryPrice * (100 +  v3takeprofit_input))/100
    currStopPrice = (currEntryPrice *(100 - v3stoploss_input))/100
    if low <= currStopPrice and IsLong()
        
    
        strategy.exit("Stop Loss Hit", "Long", limit=currStopPrice)

    if high >= curTpPrice and IsLong()
  
        strategy.exit("Take Profit Hit", "Long", stop=curTpPrice)
```